# Run out of memory when posting photo to database android

Tags: java, android, imageview, arrays, android-volley

I'm trying to send a photo to my database using volley as a `byte[]` converted into a `String`. This is where I called my volley method and obtain the `String` from the image which is inside the `ImageView`:

```
addPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView pic_holder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picturedisplay);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)pic_holder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
            String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
            MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
            myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(), locationResult);
            boolean r = myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(),
                    locationResult);
            if (!r) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder1.setMessage("Please enable your GPS.");
                builder1.setCancelable(false);
                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
            else {
                savePhoto(Latitude,Longitude,username,picText,img_str);
            }
```

This is my volley method:

```
public void savePhoto(final Double latitude, final Double longitude, final String username, final String description,final String picture ) {
    pDialog.setMessage("Posting picture..");
    pDialog.show();

    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SL_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your picture has been posted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("latitude", Double.toString(latitude));
            hashMap.put("longitude", Double.toString(longitude));
            hashMap.put("image",picture);
            hashMap.put("user", username);
            hashMap.put("description", description);
            return hashMap;
        }
    };
    queue.add(request);
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
02-22 21:33:54.350 5233-5240/citylife.com.city W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.926ms
02-22 21:33:58.310 5233-5233/citylife.com.city I/Choreographer: Skipped 707 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 21:33:59.090 5233-5233/citylife.com.city D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
02-22 21:34:01.860 5233-5240/citylife.com.city W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.464ms
02-22 21:34:05.360 5233-5240/citylife.com.city W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.127ms
02-22 21:34:06.350 5233-5248/citylife.com.city W/art: Suspending all threads took: 100.142ms
02-22 21:34:06.390 5233-5240/citylife.com.city W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.192ms
02-22 21:34:06.410 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16(496B) AllocSpace objects, 1(25MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 60MB/68MB, paused 962us total 53.527ms
02-22 21:34:06.410 5233-5248/citylife.com.city I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 53.981ms for cause Background
02-22 21:34:06.490 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 9.452ms for cause Alloc
02-22 21:34:06.500 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1(32B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 79MB/87MB, paused 1.008ms total 7.842ms
02-22 21:34:06.530 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(256B) AllocSpace objects, 1(18MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 60MB/68MB, paused 1.099ms total 26.534ms
02-22 21:34:06.570 5233-5248/citylife.com.city W/art: Suspending all threads took: 39.015ms
02-22 21:34:06.610 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(224B) AllocSpace objects, 1(18MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 70MB/78MB, paused 940us total 29.766ms
02-22 21:34:06.690 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 96MB to 96MB
02-22 21:34:06.690 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 88MB/96MB, paused 1.176ms total 18.263ms
02-22 21:34:06.700 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2(64B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 88MB/96MB, paused 956us total 7.052ms
02-22 21:34:06.750 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 96MB to 96MB
02-22 21:34:06.750 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 88MB/96MB, paused 972us total 50.996ms
02-22 21:34:06.750 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 9MB allocation
02-22 21:34:06.780 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 96MB to 96MB
02-22 21:34:06.780 5233-5276/citylife.com.city I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13(408B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 88MB/96MB, paused 1.060ms total 28.205ms
02-22 21:34:06.780 5233-5276/citylife.com.city E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 9606684 byte allocation with 8049319 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"
02-22 21:34:06.800 5233-5276/citylife.com.city E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3159
                                                                 Process: citylife.com.city, PID: 5233
                                                                 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9606684 byte allocation with 8049319 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
                                                                     at java.nio.charset.Charsets.toUtf8Bytes(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:775)
                                                                     at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:759)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:452)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:435)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:236)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
```

Comment: you either need to scale your image down some or send your image in chunks (which I dont know if volley supports)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to scale down the image?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I managed to get it to send now, I am however receiving this error `com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)`

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with Bitmaps since they are very big and you get this error.
Using `android:largeHeap="true"` in your application tag in the manifest file worked for me, since you have more space initially, but this will still not solve the problem 100% so just try and minimize the use of memory, create the bitmap, use it, and get rid of it, thus try to not store them into a list or a map.

Comment: How would you recommend I send the photo to the database? It's getting sent to a php script on the server which inserts it into the mysqli database

Comment: I would say if you can, then send it right away, if you have no access (no internet or something) store them to the SQLite, thus on the phone DB, then when you have internet again, check what is in the local DB and send them to the server, so this way you will not have them into the memory.

Comment: if the image is from device storage. You can send image as a file to server. Use loopj asynchttpclient library instead of volley. Very easy .

Comment: @SreeAndroidDev basically I take the photo with the camera, display it on screen in the imageview, the user has the option of storing it in the phone but doesn't have to, then when he presses the send button it is send to the server, he also has the option of deleting it and the photo isn't stored anywhere. This is the behaviour I want to achieve, so if he doesn't choose to save it on the phone I can't really grab it from the storage.

Comment: Ok so this way you only have one image at the time in the memory, so you should be fine, no need to store anything.